# w3wp.exe increase,not decrease this increase when i use a webservice how to configurate?

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7, connection-pooling, pool

[image]

i have one webservice, when i consume it,  w3wp.exe increase, then if i consume many times this continue increasing, when this is around 24,000 and i try consume it, i don get answer,
what do i need configurate, and how do i configurate, because not aument, or after consume, this decrease again. Actually  this decrease after 1 hour or 30 minutes.
do i need configurate it in web.config or  is it a configuration in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS worker processes continue to grow until they reach an execution time or size limit, and a number of other criteria. They are then recycled with a new process that starts off at the initial memory use. This is by design and permits the application to respond better to multiple similar requests.

These options are described at [Configuring Recycling Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).